# Onain saying Kadish for parent's Yahrzheit

Tags: halacha, death, kaddish

An Onain is not obligated to do Mitzvos Asei. An Onain does not Daven, nor make Brachos. Suppose a person is an Onain, and that day is his father's or mother's Yahrzheit, does he say Kaddish for them? (sources)

Comment: Do you have any reason to think Kaddish for a parent's Yahrzheit would be an exception to the rule you stated?

Comment: No. However I saw an Onain, who is a well versed fellow do so this week. Perhaps after Shiva is over I can ask him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 196:9; "*an Onain says Kaddish if he has Yahrzeit for a parent, or is in his "11 months" Availut for them*". But he seems to be referring to Shabbat.

In 26:12 he says that one who could not say Kaddish during the day - for whatever reason - can say Kaddish for a Yarzeit the evening after.